# Convert an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a method that returns the year and month between a set of dates.

```
d = (from..to).map {|d| [ d.year, d.month ] }.uniq
```

I can iterate over each element like so:

```
d.each do |elm|
  #For Year
  puts elm[0]

  #For Month Number
  puts elm[1]
end
```

How can I change the method so that I can iterate as follows to enhance the readability of the code and in general make it easier as well?

```
elm.month_number
elm.year
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for array auto-unpacking as described here: [How to iterate over an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296739/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-of-arrays)

```
d = (from..to).map {|d| [ d.year, d.month ] }.uniq

d.each do |year, month|
  # For Year
  puts year

  #For Month Number
  puts month
end
```

Comment: That is not what the OP asked for, but is the recommended way.

Comment: Do you mean that the OP asked for `elm.month` and this way uses simply `month` instead?  If that's the case, I'd say you're technically right, but is that really a significant difference? Is there any reason to prefer `elm.month` to `month`?

Comment: This does the job of what I needed, Thanks! Perhaps I was not that clear on the question. Apologies for that

Comment: @sawa answered after me and I actually think his solution is significantly better in the sense that it is cleaner and less roundabout.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class or a structure. e.g.

```
YearMonth = Struct.new(:year, :month)
d = (from..to).map{|d| YearMonth.new(d.year, d.month)}.uniq
```

although, this is not an optimal way of doing it. Consider this:

```
d = (from.year .. to.year).flat_map { |year|
  from_month = year == from.year ? from.month : 1
  to_month = year == to.year ? to.month : 12
  (from_month..to_month).map { |month| YearMonth.new(year, month) }
}
```

This avoids creating a huge array of dates, and another array that results from a `map`, and goes straight for months (even if it is not as compact).

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is redundant. Keep the date elements as is (I assume they are `Date` objects).

```
d = (from..to).to_a.uniq_by{|elm| [elm.year, elm.month]}

class Date
  alias month_number month
end

d.each do |elm|
  elm.year
  ...
  elm.month_number
  ...
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return each day, not each month?

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work because I agree with you that it seems less roundabout than my solution. But I can't get it to work: with `from` and `to` as Date objects, I get `undefined method uniq for Range`. With some googling it looks like `Range#map` (like the OP used) is the only way to go ... `Range#to_a` returns an empty set. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I missed `to_a`.

Comment: `(Date.new(2015,11,1)..Date.new(2015,5,1)).to_a` returns `[]` ...?

Comment: haha don't mind, me, that should be from `2015,5,1` to `2015,11,1`

Comment: I got a `NoMethodError` for `Array#uniq_by` with a block, but `Array#uniq` with a block worked as expected. Are you sure it's not `Array#uniq` that you're going for?  Looks like `Array#uniq_by` is deprecated http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this too (create a `CustomDate` class with `year` and `month` attributes):

```
class CustomDate
  attr_accessor :year, :month

  def initialize(year, month)
    self.year = year
    self.month = month
  end
end

(from..to).map { |d| CustomDate.new(d.year, d.month) }.uniq.each do |e|
  puts "year: #{e.year}"
  puts "month: #{e.month}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some great discussion in the other answers, but it seems silly to iterate over all 365 days in each year just to get 12 date objects when it's not at all necessary.

Instead of iterating from `from` to `to`, calculate an integer number of months from each and then iterate over that range. Take a look:

```
from = Date.civil(2013, 7, 1)
to = Date.civil(2015, 11, 23)

from_mos = 12 * from.year + from.month - 1
to_mos = 12 * to.year + to.month - 1

dates = (from_mos..to_mos).map do |mos|
  year, month = mos.divmod(12)
  Date.civil(year, month + 1, 1)
end
```

Now `dates` is an Enumerable yielding a Date for the first day of each month, i.e. 2013-07-01, 2013-08-01, … 2015-11-01, which you can use as below;

```
dates.each do |date|
  puts "Year #{date.year}, month #{date.month}"
end
# => Year 2013, month 7
#    Year 2013, month 8
#    ...
#    Year 2015, month 10
#    Year 2015, month 11
```

P.S. If you want to go to the trouble of defining a class or Struct, I recommend making it work directly with the Range API:

```
YearMonth = Struct.new(:year, :month) do
  def succ
    next_year, next_month = months.succ.divmod(12)
    self.class.new(next_year, next_month + 1)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    months <=> other.months
  end

  protected
  def months
    12 * year + month - 1
  end
end
```

Now you can just do this:

```
from = YearMonth.new(2013, 7)
to = YearMonth.new(2015, 11)

(from..to).each do |ym|
  puts "Year #{ym.year}, month #{ym.month}"
end
```